# i want to create element (span or div) with style( specific background-color) into parent element when click on btn?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vs-web-site-project

i want to create element (span or div) with style( specific background-color) into parent element when click on btn ?

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
blackback = document.createElement("span"),
styleSpan = blackback.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
body.appendChild(styleSpan);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? remove the "styleSpan =" anyway

Answer (score 0):

This line was wrong : `styleSpan = blackback.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";`

You didn't need to reassign when giving the style to blackback and you needed to pass the blackback to the appendChild method because this is the element you've tried to create.

Try like this :

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var blackback = document.createElement("span");
  blackback.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  blackback.style.width= "250px";
  blackback.style.height= "250px";
  body.appendChild(blackback);
}
```

Comment: try checking in the developer if the element is exists or not in the dom. I believe its there but just have no content/height/width

Comment: I edited my example, try now. does it work now?

Comment: there is not mistake at code why not working ?